# Увеличить ширину текстового курсора при transform: scale

Tags: html, css, курсор, contenteditable

В следующем сниппете два div'а выглядят одинаково, хотя первый отображён в масштабе 1:1, а второй уменьшен в 10 раз. Но есть одна проблема: при редактировании второго div'а текстовый курсор очень тонкий и почти (а то и совсем) не виден. Как исправить?

[image: обычный div с курсором]
[image: смасштабированный div с курсором]

Это скриншоты из Хрома.
В FF и Опере 12 во втором блоке курсор вообще не отображается.
А вот в IE11 Win7 всё хорошо.

Хотелось бы нормальный вариант для Хрома и/или FF.

```css
html {
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

div {
  font-size: 40px;
}

section {
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section div {
  transform-origin: top left;
  font-size: 400px;
  transform: scale(.1);
  width: 1000%;
}

section:focus-within {
  outline: 2px solid rgba(77, 144, 254, .5);
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}

section:focus-within :focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Usual contenteditable div</div>
<section><div contenteditable>Scaled contenteditable div</div></section>
```

Comment: В чате я запостил [правку вашей предвыборной речи](https://pastebin.com/TB4zYKXD): исправление грамматических ошибок и оформления ссылок. Николас счёл это "неуважением". Правка самоуничтожится через день — тогда она потеряет актуальность, так как возможность править речь будет отключена.

Comment: @Squidward,насколько я понимаю, убрать картинки в ссылки внутри текста. Не уверен, что это хорошая идея, т. к. я в ссылках в тексте обычно ожидаю обычные страницы, а не скриншоты.

Comment: Аргумент принимается, хотя я не очень понимаю, зачем давать ссылки на картинки, если можно давать полноценные ссылки на посты, если честно. Там ещё грамматика исправлена кроме ссылок. В комментариях вам указали далеко не всё.

Comment: @Squidward, заметил изменение двоеточия только. Посмотрю повнимательнее. Там не всё, что на скринах общедоступно. Например, для просмотра удалённого поста надо 10К.